# How to check which radio button a user checked if not in a form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a textfile with information that I am using to create a quiz. I am only displaying one quiz question at a time however. I am generating radio buttons based on the number of questions and then I have a submit button after the loop that generates the radio buttons. I can't figure out how to get which radio button the user selected in the $_POST array when I click submit. My initial thought is to use a form tag and then have the loop run but I don't know if this works or how to make it work syntactically.

textfile (the last number is the index of the right answer):

```
What does charmander evolve to?#Charmeleon:charizard:squirtle#0
WHo is the main character in Pokemon?#Misty:Ash:Obama#1
```

Script:

```
<?php

        $indexTemp = intVal($_SESSION["index"]);

        if($_SESSION["numQuestions"] == $indexTemp){
            echo "Your Results are: ";
            echo "<form action=\"process.php\" method=\"post\"> Back to Main screen: <input type=\"submit\"><br \> </form>";
            exit();
        }

        $filename = $_SESSION["quizOfTheDay"];

        $quizStuff = file($filename);
        $ctr =1;


        $questionInfo = $quizStuff[$indexTemp];

        $questionParse = explode("#", $questionInfo);
        $_SESSION["correctAns"] = $questionParse[2];
        echo $_SESSION["correctAns"]." from line 55 <br />";
        $answerChoices = explode(":",$questionParse[1]);

        echo "$questionParse[0] ? <br />";
        #This is where the radio buttons are being generated
        foreach ($answerChoices as $answerChoice) {
                echo "<input type='radio' name='ans$ctr' id='q1' value='$ctr'> <label for='q1'> $answerChoice </label> <br />";
                $ctr +=1;
            }
        $_SESSION["index"] = $indexTemp +1;
        echo "<form action=\"questions.php\" method=\"post\"> <input type=\"submit\"><br \> </form>";


    ?>
```

Comment: Just echo `<form>` above the foreach and echo `<input type="submit" /></form>` after it? Also you shouldn't dynamicly create unique names for each radiobutton. That will make each button selectable at the same time. All answers need the same name value. The id values should be unique though. General rule: IDs should ALWAYS be unique.

Comment: Radio inputs should have the same name but different values, don't change the `name`. Then you just check the value of `$_POST['ans']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obtaining data from radio buttons and checkboxes can be a little tricky, generally due to a lack of understanding of how radio buttons and checkboxes work.

It is important to remember two facts:

1. Checkbox "Names" Must Be Unique to Each Checkbox
2. Radio Button "Names" Must Be Identical For Each Group of Buttons

[image]

Update the foreach since you must have `same name` for all the radio buttons but with different values.

```
<?php
foreach ($answerChoices as $answerChoice) {
echo "<input type='radio' name='ans' id='q1' value=".$ctr."> <label for='q1'>".$answerChoice."</label> <br />";
$ctr +=1;
}
?>
```

Now your for-each concatenation also looks wrong and i have updated it and since the concatenation is wrong the value will not be displayed in the radio button. The radio button value will be the count of the increment variable.

Comment: Thanks for the response! As a follow up, do I need to add a form tag before the for loop in order to access the value after the submit is hit?

Answer (score 0):

remove $ctr

```
foreach ($answerChoices as $answerChoice) {
                echo "<input type='radio' name='ans' id='q1' value='$ctr'> <label for='q1'> $answerChoice </label> <br />";
                $ctr +=1;
            }
```